# Google Cloud AI Platform: Image Data Labeling Service Error - Image URI not valid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

Error in Google Cloud Data labeling Service:

- I am trying to create a dataset of images in Google's Data labeling service.
- Using a single image to test it out.
- Created a Google storage bucket named: my-bucket
- Uploaded an image to my-bucket - image file name: testcat.png
- Created and uploaded a csv file (UTF-8) with URI path of image stored inside it.
- image URI path as stored in csv file: gs://my-bucket//testcat.png
- Named the csv file : testimage.csv
- Uploaded the csv file in the gs bucket - my-bucket.
- i.e. testimage.csv, and testcat.png are in the same google storage bucket (my-bucket).

When I try to create the datasset in google console, GCP gives me the following error message:

** Failed to import dataset gs://my-bucket/testcat.png is not a valid
youtube uri nor a readable file path.**

I've checked multiple times and the URI for this image in Google is exactly the same as what I've used. I've tried at least 10-15 times ... the error persists.

Any one faced and successfully resolved this issue?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in our [AI Platform Data Labeling Service documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/data-labeling/docs), there is a service update due to the coronavirus (COVID-19) health emergency that states that data labeling services are limited or unavailable until further notice.

- You can't start new data labeling tasks through the Cloud Console, Google Cloud SDK, or the API
- You can request data labeling tasks only through email at cloudml-data-customer@google.com
- New data labeling tasks can't contain personally identifiable information